# Selecting multiple rows and columns based on their value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with rows and column (below a subset with only one row). They each have either a *False* or *True* value.

[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WokTQ.png)

I am trying to select a subset of all rows and columns which have a *True* value.

I tried using loc and iloc but because I do not have the name of the rows and columns (they are indexes), it does not work.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Also there is only one row? So need `df.loc[:, df.iloc[0]]` ?

Comment: Hello, thank you this is exactly what I needed !